# Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined

Tags: css, node.js, stylus

Estou obtendo o **ERRO** abaixo ao tentar implementar uma estilização no meu projeto com *Stylus*. O mesmo acontece para `background: url(...);` e acho que para qualquer outra tentativa relacionada.

Encontrei no *Github* alguns problemas semelhantes, mas nenhuma das soluções funcionou neste caso.

Estou utilizando o plugin [`gulp-stylus`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-stylus) e já utilizei antes, mas tudo sempre correu normalmente.

```
Cannot read property 'nodes' of undefined
    at ".section-partition" (/media/idlua/Arquivo 1/Development/Projects/project/src/css/_areas/_areas-global.styl:8:98)

Details:
    lineno: 14
    column: 75
    filename: /media/idlua/Arquivo 1/Development/Projects/project/src/css/_areas/_areas-global.styl
    stylusStack:     at ".section-partition" (/media/idlua/Arquivo 1/Development/Projects/project/src/css/_areas/_areas-global.styl:8:98)
```

Trecho do código que gera o **ERRO** (quando retiro a estilização do `bg` funciona):

```
.section-partition
  content ""
  display block
  width 100%
  height 1px
  margin 1em auto
  background-image linear-gradient(to left $color_1n, $color_2n, $color_1n)
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar causando?

Comment: Já testaste com valores fixes em vêz de variáveis como `$color_1n`?

Comment: Tentei, mas obtive o mesmo erro. Mas descobri o problema; era apenas o nome do diretório onde estava o projeto. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri qual era o problema: apenas o nome do diretório onde estava o projeto. Havia um `#` no nome da pasta e isto estava confundindo o Node a encontrar os imports nos arquivos css.